# Distribution of the mean of a random weighted sample with no repetition

Tags: distributions, sampling, multinomial-distribution

**TL;DR** I want to compute the distribution of the mean of a sample obtained by the weighted sampling of $m$ elements out of $n$.

I'm working on an algorithm that learns from noisy data, and tries to separate the noise from the clean data.

I have two **constant** and known vectors of size $n$:

- $C_i \in \{0,1\}$ denotes whether sample $i$ is clean (1 if clean, 0 if noisy)
- $w_i$ is a weight with which sample $i$ should be selected

I'm taking a sample $S$ of size $m < n$ from $C$ without repetition using the weights $w_i$, and I'm interested in characterizing the distribution of the mean of $S$. In my application case, the mean of $S$ will represent the mean "cleanliness" of my selection.

As a computer scientist, I'm tempted to just run a large number of samplings and record the empirical means and measure their mean and standard deviation, but I'm guessing this is a fairly common problem with a proper analytical solution, although the non-repetitiveness might make such solution harder to find.

Comment: Some extra details might be useful for an analytic solution. Roughly how large are $m$ and $n$? Is $n$ much larger than $m$? Is the mean of $C$ close to 0 or 1?

Comment: They are both very large, you can assume $n$ is around a billion. You can assume $m=0.8*n$. The mean of $C$ is around $0.85$.